# Git project configure in Jenkins

Tags: xcode, git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to automate build for my Xcode project using Jenkins plugin, while configuring I am getting error in sourcecode management . Please see the screenshot[image]

Comment: nothing seems to be wrong here. can you try with some public repository first ? if it works, there is something wrong bitbucket url.. 

Also you can try executing the git ls-remote in command prompt. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote. let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You need **declaring Git credential** *before* the step what you show in the screenshot.